# Pandas: Drop observations based on conditions and nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe called `df` and want to drop all observations where `df['duplicate']==True` and where `df['Name']=nan`. I tried the following line of code, but it doesn't seem to work because there is something wrong with the second condition. The first condition works on its own.

`df = df.drop(df[(df.duplicate == True) & (df.Name==np.nan)].index)`

I also tried writing `df.Name=='nan'` instead, but it also doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: got a quick reply, `df.Name.isna()` solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: `df.Name.isna()`

Comment: Thanks, that was quick to solve!